# SQL Server 2008 and MySQL Daily Backups

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-backups

Is there a quick and easy way to backup both SQL Server 2008 and MySQL, all their databases?

Right now I have a batch script that runs, but I have to manually add a database each and every time, and I'm sick of maintaining it. So I want to set it up to backup all SQL Server and then all MySQL, I dont care if its two different solutions, just want the ability to backup all the databases without having to type them in.

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with making the script first execute the SHOW DATABASES, and then backing up database?

Comment: I was really wanted someone to post a better way than scripts to do this, but I guess they all cost $$$

Comment: this might be a great question for serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks Randy, I'm new to SF and it has been my saving grace for the last couple of days, so I figured I'd try.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2008 - sure. Set up a maintenance bach, tell it to back up all (all user) databases, finished. WIll run regularly and back up the database set asked for. MySQL - no idea.